# How to combine 3 TIFF images into 1 PNG image with python?

Tags: python, image, png, tiff

I have 1 tif image for each RGB colour channel, and I would like to combine the 3 images to make a single RGB image with all 3 channels in png format using python. I have tried several experiments using the PIL library but I can't get it.

I uploaded 3 sample images to Google Drive [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1izoLeUmmlMhEkyilzpJQ3oXkS264Vff7?usp=sharing). Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your 28 pixel images aren't very useful for testing.

Comment: I have to create models for classification with these images , so I have no other choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you are really trying to achieve...

If you want an accurate merge of the 3 channels, you should probably use the `tifffile` module to understand the floating point values in your input files and accurately represent them in your output files. In fact, `gdal` would probably be even better as it understands the GeoTIFF tags in your file. `PIL` is unable to handle RGB float32 images.

If you want something that vaguely allows some sort of approximate visualisation as a PNG, you will need to do some work to scale your values to something sensible (but not accurate) because PNG cannot represent float data like your images contain.

---

Here is a more accurate merge of your channels with `tifffile`:

```
from tifffile import imread, imwrite
import numpy as np

r = imread('r.tif')
g = imread('g.tif')
b = imread('b.tif')
RGB = np.dstack((r,g,b))
imwrite('result.tif', RGB)
```

---

With PIL you would use `Image.merge()` but your data is float, so you will need to convert it to `uint8/uint16` first to get something you can store in a PNG:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open images
red   = Image.open('red_channel.tif')
green = Image.open('green_channel.tif')
blue  = Image.open('blue_channel.tif')

# Convert PIL Images to Numpy arrays
npRed   = np.array(red)
npGreen = np.array(green)
npBlue  = np.array(blue)

# Get rid of the pesky -3.4e+38 marker for out-of-bounds pixels
npRed[npRed < 0]     = 0
npBlue[npBlue < 0]   = 0
npGreen[npGreen < 0] = 0

# Find maximum across all channels for scaling
max = np.max([npRed,npGreen,npBlue])

# Scale all channels equally to range 0..255 to fit in a PNG (could use 65,535 and np.uint16 instead)
R = (npRed * 255/max).astype(np.uint8)
G = (npGreen * 255/max).astype(np.uint8)
B = (npBlue * 255/max).astype(np.uint8)

# Build a PNG
RGB = np.dstack((R,G,B))
Image.fromarray(RGB).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: How would the images be scaled to fit into a 16-bit PNG?

Comment: I have tried the code you indicate above and the result is not correct, it is a black and white image.

Comment: Like I said, your input images are really poor - there is no discernible detail, no idea of what you expect to see as a result and the ranges are weird and will not fit in a PNG anyway. Hold on a while and I'll try and make a better answer.

Comment: This solution is not what I expected. The final result contains no information of interest

Comment: Ok, can you help by showing me what you expected, and why,  please?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Your proposal is correct!

Comment: Ok, cool - I'm glad you got it working!